# How to select a volume in Potree and dowload the points as LAS file

Tags: potree

Me and my team want to be able to select a volume in the Potree web interface and dowload the points inside it as a LAS file.

We found that if you add “viewer.setServer("<url>");” in the Html, a button will appear called “Prepare Download” in the “Scene” tab under the “Properties” section when you select a volume with the volume mesurement tool. Unfortunately, we do not know what the <url> is meant to do and how to make it work. We think that this may be the potential solution we are looking for. Can you point us in the right direction?